# Reading and Striping a text file

Tags: python, string, strip

```
import re

f= ('HelloHowAreYou')
f = re.sub(r"([a-z\d])([A-Z])", r'\1 \2', f)
# Makes the string space separated. You can use split to convert it to list
f = f.split()
print (f)
```

this works fine to separate all the string of text by capital letters, however when i then change the code to read a text file i have issues. can anyone shed some light why?

to read a file I'm using:

```
f = open('words.txt','r')
```

Answer (score 1):

> to read a file I'm using:
>
> f = open('words.txt','r')

But that code doesn't read the file, it only opens it. Try:

```
my_file = open('words.txt','r')
f = file.read()
my_file.close()
```

Or

```
with open('words.txt','r') as my_file:
    f = my_file.read()
```